# bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js and fullcalendar integration throws erroneous result

Tags: bootstrap-4, fullcalendar, bootstrap-datetimepicker

https://jsfiddle.net/ryan_ramsumair/2re89wpf/15/
https://jsfiddle.net/ryan_ramsumair/2re89wpf/15/#&togetherjs=FLNS5Vadhh

The above is a working link to the full code for the issue.

I am pushing the date selected from fullcalendar with the following code

```
$('#startdatetime').data("DateTimePicker").date(moment(start).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'));
```

Its displayed in the modal with

```
 <div class="form-group ">
 <label for="Patient" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Start Date & Time</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="startdatetime"
```

Strange enough , this works perfectly for any date selected from the 1st to the 13th of the month.
But anything after the 13th , it does not work.

The console .log shows that the date is being fetched properly from fullcalendar

```
console.log(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
```

Its very strange...

I added the full working code on the jsfiddle link , if anyone can assist.

Comment: Would the fact that it is having issues with the 13th have something to do with that number perhaps being treated as a month, which doesn't exist?

Comment: In that first fiddle, if I click on February 7 it displays as 07/02/2019 in the modal but if I click on that box it opens up a calendar for July 2 ... seems to be getting a bit mixed up...

Comment: This makes sense , its probably not taking the date in that format (dd/mm/yy) its still pushing it as mm/dd/yy therefore 13 and onwards is invalid.Thanks , ill work out an alternative

Comment: Better to use a non-ambiguous format such as yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mhluzi/1ku84sfw/2/):

I changed your startdatetime function to

```
   $(function() {
      $('#startdatetime').datetimepicker(
      {format:'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'});
   });
```

Hope that helps.